# Formula to Distribute Items Among Constrainted Bins

Tags: combinatorics

If $xyz$ is an integer formed from rolling 3 dice in order. How many integers can be formed such that the sum of the three dice creates an integer such that  $x+y+z=14$.

I know I can write out all the scenarios (6,6,2), (5,6,3), etc. But is there a formula that can be used to find all the cominations with the restrictions that each integer is between 1 and 6 without having to tediously write out all possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is...but its not pretty. If you look at it probabilistically, you are asking for the probability that the sum of three uniform, discrete variables defined on [1,2,...6] = 14. To turn this into an integer from a probability, you multiply by $6^3$, which is all the different outcomes from three dice (I am assuming you care about permutations of the three face values). The tricky part is getting the distribution of three uniform random variables, which invovles two applications of a discrete convolution operation.

Comment: Thank you for you comment. Well, is there an efficient way to enumerate all the possible combinations? One way I start this problem is to take exteremr situations. If I max out the first slot at 6, and the second slot at 6 that leaves me with a w for the last. How can I use this extereme to efficiently organize and enumerate the possibilities

Comment: See discrete convolution: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution#Discrete_convolution. Let X,Y,Z be three uniform(1,6) discrete RVs. Then you need to calculate: C=X*Y, then T=C*Z, where * is the discrete convolution. In essence, the dicrete convolution systematically enumerates the possiblities but you don't have to manually go through and do it. You can get the formula from a CAS. Computationally, I don't know how much more "efficient" it is relative to brute enumeration, but it is more systematic and can be automated to some degree. Unfortunately, it will not be a simple formula.

Comment: Also, a simple algorithm for this would be to condition on one die value then count the number of ways to make up the difference between the other two (similar to what you wrote above). In this case, X=1 has no possibilities, X=2 has 1, X=3 has 2, X=4 has 3 , X=5 has 4 and X=6 has 5. So, you get $\sum\limits_{i=2}^6 (i-1)$ which has a very common formula for the sum of consecutive integers: $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for n integers. Here n=5, so you get 15. Your next step could be to generalize this approach to other values than x+y+z=14. Hope that helps.